# CakePhp login(): не срабатывает авторизация

Tags: cakephp, php

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не срабатывает авторизация. Ввожу логин и пароль, но меня не перенаправляет на нужную страницу.

AppController

```
 <?php
    class AppController extends Controller {

        public $components = array('Auth');

        public function beforeFilter() { 
            $this->layout='';
            $this->Auth->allow('view');
            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller'=>'players', 'action'=>'index');
            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'login');
        } 
    } 
    ?>

UsersController

<?php

class UsersController extends AppController{         
    public function login()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {       
            if($this->Auth->login())
            {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            }

        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }   
}
?>
```

Login.ctp

```
<table id="login" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <form action="../users/login" method="post">
<tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">
            Аутентификация пользователя
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label><b>Username :</b></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="25" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label><b>Password :</b></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="25" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="autologin" name="remember"/>
            <label  for="autologin">Запомнить меня</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="submit" id="entry" name="entry" value="Выполнить вход"/></br>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался в проблеме, оказывается Auth компонент при отправке формы хэширует пароль, в базе он у меня был в обычном виде, поэтому все время отказывало в авторизации!